# Colors render much darker on Safari than on Chrome/other browsers

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, mobile-safari, anime.js

I have a color gradient animated with anime.js. Looks great on Chrome. When I run the site on Safari (mobile or desktop) The same colors are rendered noticibly darker to the point where it is unappealing and nothing like the other browsers. The colors are hex values and safari dev tools say they are being rendered accurately but visually they are way off.

This is an example of a gradient:

```
`linear-gradient(10deg, #f52828, transparent),linear-gradient(120deg, #Cc33ff, transparent),linear-gradient(240deg, #Ff9933, transparent)``
```

I don't have any idea what is causing this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check if you have any strange profile enabled on these devices.

Comment: @GrzegorzT. as far as can tell, it does not seem to be device specific. Every iPhone and Mac I've tested experiences this.